# center middle li of evenly spread li in a ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jacky_lei/91fg280v/) of my issue. I want to evenly distribute an unknown number of `li`s inside a ul. But as you can see from the fiddle, the middle li is not directly under the the header, so it's not correctly centered. Also if you inspect each of the `li`s, they have different widths.

How do I fix it so that the middle `li` will always be in the middle, so as to align with the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method # 01:**

Add `table-layout: fixed` in styles of `.strweak-list`.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.strweak-header {
  text-align: center;
}
.strweak-list {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h5 class='strweak-header'>strongAgainst</h5>
<ul class="strweak-list">
  <li class="cell">water</li>
  <li class="cell">ghost</li>
  <li class="cell">ground</li>
</ul>
```

**Method # 02:**

You can use css [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as well:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
ader {
  text-align: center;
}
.strweak-header {
  text-align: center;
}
.strweak-list {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.strweak-list li {
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<h5 class='strweak-header'>strongAgainst</h5>
<ul class="strweak-list">
  <li>water</li>
  <li>ghost</li>
  <li>ground</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}





.strweak-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.strweak-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h5 class='strweak-header'>strongAgainst</h5>
<ul class="strweak-list">
  <li>water</li>
  <li>ghost</li>
  <li>ground</li>
</ul>
```

This is how you do it in flexbox. Hope it helps! Cheers!